# Webpage load slow in iPhone safari on some devices

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

Here are 2 devices, tested to the same page

**iPhone 1** safari load the web page, it blank for around 3~4 seconds

[image: Safari show blank screen for 3 seconds]

**iPhone 2** we can see the page load as normal

[image: Safari load webpage as normal]

Why would the same web page, same browser, behave differently in different devices?

What are the possible causes for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The internet speed for 2 iphones isp might be different. Go to fast.com to know your internet speed

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache of the device which is slow.The more cache makes the web page load longer.